# CiviCRM for animal rescue charity

Tags: wordpress, evaluating-civicrm

CiviCRM newbie here. I am interested in whether CiviCRM and Wordpress could be used to manage an Animal rescue and rehousing charity.
In addition to tracking all the usual stuff like donations, events, volunteers, etc., they would need to manage:

- Details of each rescued Animal and all relevant details such as location (foster home or adopted home, kennels, etc.), medical info, statistics, etc.
- Lists of available foster homes
- Adoption applications

Ideally, a solution that could list available animals on Public Wordpress Website, from the backend.

Is CiviCRM something that could handle this scenario, without too much additional development?

Thank you.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Look into CiviCase for planning and tracking each animal's adoption appointments, vet visits, groomings, etc.

CiviEvent has integrated location/venue components that might be useful in organizing your fostering and other volunteer activities.

CiviContribute would be my first choice in setting up adoption applications, complete with payment tracking and reporting.

Short answer, yes: it can be done with CiviCRM on a WordPress site. Might even find the BuddyPress plugin useful in tandem with Civi to energize social communication and networking among volunteers and related animal advocates.

Good luck Mark!

Answer (score 5):

While it is not currently possible to create new top level contact types, alongside Individuals, Households and Organisations, there is nothing stopping you having a sub-type of eg Organisations that you call Animals, or sub-types of Individuals called Cat, Dog, etc (thx Coleman).

Having set up the sub-type you can then add Custom Fields to that, eg Animal type (cat, dog, alligator etc).

You can also add custom fields for eg Date Arrived, Date adopted, etc.

You can also create custom Relationship Types so eg Adopter is, Adopted by.

You can then use Profiles to display listings of Animails etc.

In terms of what WordPress offers, it has less options than Drupal, and there might be somethings that I or other drupal users would then say 'ah but you could do that more easily with drupal'. But if that becomes a significant issue for you then you can have Drupal in front of CiviCRM, and theme it to match your WP site, but that is undoubtedly adding extra effort.

Comment: I'd probably make sub-types of Individuals called Cat, Dog, etc.