# Dog as sub-contact type of individual but they have no last name

Tags: sub-types

We've seen references to use a individual sub-contact type ([CiviCRM for animal rescue charity](https://civicrm.stackexchange.com/questions/19711/civicrm-for-animal-rescue-charity/19714#19714)) but the issue is dogs do not have last names. Atleast, not always ;)

So how have people handled this? Adding in a placeholder for last name is a workaround I want to avoid. I think the best situation is to disable last name only for a certain sub-contact type or add in the CID to the last name field.

Answer (score 2):

Depends what you want to do with the dog contacts, but another option for your last name question would be to use a sub-type of Organization rather than Individual since that only requires a single name.

Comment: We loose the demographics block with that which is nice because it calculates age.

Answer (score 1):

I'm assuming the dog doesn't have email? Then again, it's almost the year 2020. All joking aside, if the org were to register a .dog domain name (which does exist), they could assign emails for the dogs and maybe get some publicity along with it. Then last name becomes optional.

https://donuts.domains/what-we-do/top-level-domains